# Is there a messaging service between Java and C++ such as JMS for Java to Java?

Tags: java, c++, messaging

I am well aware of the Java Messaging Service (JMS) for sending messages from Java code to Java code. Also I am aware of CORBA which is a integration programming that helps in binding different programming languages together so that they can communicate between themselves through objects.

But I was wondering if there a common messaging service such as JMS for different languages so as to send a message from Java to C++ and vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

I'd highly recommend starting with [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) unless you need some of the features that a broker based architecture such as an implementation based on [AMQP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol) delivers (e.g. RabbitMQ).

ZeroMQ has lots of bindings including Java, C#, C++, C, however it is message based so transferring objects between different languages may better lend itself to something like OpenDDS. see [Comparing OpenDDS and ZeroMQ Usage and Performance](http://mnb.ociweb.com/mnb/MiddlewareNewsBrief-201004.html)

[Good examples of ZeroMQ](http://www.coastrd.com/zeromq-messaging) implementations, from the basic to the complex; e.g.

[image: Basic ZeroMQ Request Reply]
[image: ZeroMQ Publish Subscribe]
[image: Complex ZeroMQ Forwarder Proxy]

Answer (score 2):

Try to look to 29 West(Informatica) products like UMP. Middle ware without middle. similar to Tibco RV. Uses broadcast, multicast and unicast.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/29West. 
It does not require any brokers. Each communication participant should have UMP installed which will run transport daemon. For java there is lib that implements JMS spec, and allows to upstream and downstream messages through transports.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/). It has a lot of [bindings](http://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to set up a special server to do so(and dont want to mess with the complexity monster that is CORBA), check out Google Protocol buffers https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/

You can simply send everything over a socket(even connected to yourself if need be), no need for extra servers or configs.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://qpid.apache.org/

You have both Java/C++ broker implementations and those and some other languages can exchange messages.

Answer (score 0):

HornetQ has a STOMP and REST implementation which can be used by other languages:
[TechnicalFaqHornetQ](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HornetQTechnicalFAQ)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at Spread API (www.spread.org) to see if it fits your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I know [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/)  can get the job done.  We typically use Protocol Buffers to get our objects serialized across the wire.  XML could work to but the main thing is you don't want whatever random chunk of memory either language has decided to use to represent your objects on the wire, you want a known serialization format.

Answer (score 0):

The Data Distribution Service (DDS) is a standard by the OMG, the same group that did the CORBA spec. Standardized language bindings are C, C++, Java and Ada, but C# and others are available as well. Different languages as well as operating systems can be mixed in your system. Structured datatypes to be distributed are specified in a language-neutral format (by the standard a subset of OMG IDL), which is then translated into language-specific interfaces and datatypes to be used by your application.

The DDS specification supports many advanced data management features like a strong-typed and content aware databus, distributed state management and historical data access. Its rich set of Quality of Service settings allows to off-load a lot of the complexity from your applications to the middleware.

DDS implementations typically are highly scalable and decentralized in nature. Components participating in a DDS infrastructure are decoupled, both in space and in time. Some DDS products are deployed in numerous mission- and business-critical systems.

See [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_distribution_service) for a very brief introduction and list of references. I have specialized in DDS for more than 10 years, I still like it and I think it is one of the most useful technologies around.

Answer (score 0):

TIBCO RV, there's lots of interface for it, like Java, C, C++, .NET and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion is [OpenMQ](http://mq.java.net/downloads.html). Within its package, it includes the C header files and the library files you can link your C/C++ program with.